# Inbox font size changes after rotating (back)

Tags: bug, design, ios, font-size

When the notification inbox dialog is open on an iPhone in portrait mode, and rotating it to landscape and then back, the font size changes. See the following screenshots:

Initial (portrait):
[image]

After rotating to landscape:
[image]

After rotating back:
[image]

iOS (and hence Safari) are the most recent versions. This may be reproducible on Android smartphones, I haven't checked.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my android phone just fyi

Comment: @TheAmplitwist same bug for sure, yes. Probably something on the iOS side.